# Internet Explorer: Set homepage for all users without GPO

Tags: command-line, internet-explorer, windows-registry, powershell

I'm looking for a way to set the homepage of Internet Explorer (and possibly other browsers) for all Users through command line/Powershell, or any other method that doesn't use the domain policies (GPO).

I Want to do this on newly installed computers, where only one Administrator has logged on. So setting the registry value in HKCU won't work, because I don't know which users will log on onto the machine.

Maybe it's possible to run a script, every time a new users logs on for the first time?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach of running a script when users log onto the machine is good. I recommend you to have a look at [the Active Setup method](http://www.itninja.com/blog/view/an-active-setup-primer).

Basically, this allow you to set a particular script/executable to run once each time a user logs on (e.g a script that create a new HKCU key). Note this script will only run once for each user, except if you increment the Active Setup script version.

Just try it, you'll see it's amazing ! I use it a lot to manipulate HKCU keys for users.

Hope this helps !

Comment: Thank you Ob1lan, this was just what I was looking for!
Problem solved.